# Thread interrupts in buffered Flowable after Emitter.onComplete

Tags: rx-java

I have a `Flowable` like:

```
Flowable.<String>create(onSubscribe, BackpressureStrategy.DROP)
    .doOnSubscribe(sub -> {
        System.out.println("onSubscribe");
    })
    .onBackpressureDrop(sns2 -> LOG.warn("Backpressure, dropping " + Arrays.asList(sns2)))
    .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .doOnTerminate(() -> {
        System.out.println("onTerminate");
    })
    .onErrorReturn(error -> {
        System.out.println("Error, will cancel scan: " + error);
        throw new RuntimeException(error);
    })
    .subscribe(objs -> /* NIO work here */);
```

When I call `onComplete` on the source emitter, following immediately after the `onNext` calls, I get an interrupt inside the `subscribe` lambda. I think this is expected behaviour: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3601 . This appears to happen while the subscriber is processing the downstream objects from the buffer (I guess if it was single threaded there'd be no issue).

This is a problem because I'm performing NIO work here which has quite specific demands in terms of what happens on `Thread.interrupt`. This occurs before the buffer has completed sending all work through, so some of the `objs` are not fully processed.

Is this related to the `Scheduler`? Should I be using the IO one? How do I "protect" the work performed in the subscriber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've registered my subscriber on the IO thread:

```
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)
    .subscribe(objs -> /* NIO work here */);
```

I think I was assuming, because of the upstream `buffer`, interrupts were placed on threads from the `buffer` and this would also be done to any threads chosen by `subscribeOn`. But it appears this is not the case.

If anyone can provide a better explanation I'd like to read it.